# Google login issue in React progressive web app

Tags: reactjs

I'm using this both **npm** for google and facebook login in **React js PWA**   [googe login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react--login)
[facebook login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login)

It works fine in a chrome web app
and also in android PWA.
But when I create PWA in ios and perform google or facebook login it does not works well.

**Issue:** I clicked on the Google login button and it redirects me to google login page.
After that, I'd successfully logged in to google and instead of redirect back to the app it redirect me to browser in new page.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: From your explanation, you're trying to Authenticate users, and make them return to the app after a successful or failed authentication through either Google or Facebook? My advice will be to implement this using Google's Firestore Auth https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth, it's very easy to integrate with your React App.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I exactly want that you understand. I'll try with Google's firestore.
But please share any solution for this current library if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I use in my React app, it has all the popular Auth libraries packed in, it pops up a new browser window for login and close it to return to the app after a successful login.

Comment: Have you tried it for react PWA app?
 Because it's only not work with PWA in IOS. In chrome, it works absolutely fine.

Comment: It works well for a PWA app when converted to one too.